# Errors using AWSPowerShell in PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to work through the instructions on getting started with AWS IOT [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer). I have installed the prerequisites:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2017 with latest updates
- Windows Subsystem for Linux

But I think the page leaves some important things out. To use PowerShell I have to have some kind of AWSPowerShell or AWS Tools installed. When I run '.\provision_thing.ps1' it does some of the things but fails at Register-IOTThing and Get-IOTEndpoint. The errors I get are:

> Register-IOTThing : The 'Register-IOTThing' command was found in the
> module 'AWS.Tools.IoT', but the module could not be loaded. For more
> information, run 'Import-Module AWS.Tools.IoT'. At
> C:\Users\erics\source\repos\iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer\Dotnetsamples\provision_thing.ps1:44
> char:1
>
> - Register-IOTThing `
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Register-IOTThing:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
>   ```
>
> Get-IOTEndpoint : The 'Get-IOTEndpoint' command was found in the
> module 'AWS.Tools.IoT', but the module could not be loaded. For more
> information, run 'Import-Module AWS.Tools.IoT'. At
> C:\Users\erics\source\repos\iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer\Dotnetsamples\provision_thing.ps1:48
> char:17
> $EndpointName = Get-IOTEndpoint
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-IOTEndpoint:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
> ```

When I try to run 'Import-Module AWS.Tools.IoT' as the error suggests I get:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'AWSPowerShell' was not loaded
> because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At
> C:\Users\erics\source\repos\iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer\Dotnetsamples\provision_thing.ps1:1
> char:1
> Import-Module AWSPowerShell
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (AWSPowerShell:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
> ```

If I attempt to install AWSPowerShell using Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell I get a quite impressive and long error truncated here:

> PS
> C:\Users\erics\source\repos\iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer\Dotnetsamples>
> Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell
>
> Untrusted repository You are installing the modules from an untrusted
> repository. If you trust this repository, change its
> InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are
> you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'? [Y] Yes
> [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default
> is "N"): A PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands
> are already available on this system:'Add-ALXBContactWithAdd
> ressBook,Add-ASInstances,Add-CTTag,Add-DPTags,Add-DSIpRoutes,Add-ELBTags,Add-EMRTag,Add-ESTag,Add-MLTag,Begin-RDSDTrans action,Build-LMBV2BotLocale,Clear-AWSCredentials,Clear-AWSDefaults,Commit-RDSDTransaction,Confirm-EC2EndpointConnection
> ,Confirm-EC2ReservedInstancesExchangeQuote,Confirm-EC2TransitGatewayPeeringAttachment,Confirm-EC2TransitGatewayVpcAttac
> hment,Confirm-EC2VpcPeeringConnection,Dismount-ASInstances,Edit-EC2Hosts,Edit-RSClusterIamRoles,Enable-ORGAllFeatures,F
> ind-CTEvents,Get-AG2ApiLis,Get-ASACases,Get-ASAccountLimits,Get-ASACommunications,Get-ASAServices,Get-ASASeverityLevels
> ,Get-ASATrustedAdvisorCheckRefreshStatuses,Get-ASATrustedAdvisorChecks,Get-ASATrustedAdvisorCheckSummaries,Get-ASLifecy
> cleHooks,Get-ASLifecycleHookTypes,Get-AWSCredentials,Get-BATJobsList,Get-CDApplications,Get-CDDeployments,Get-CFCloudFr
> ontOriginAccessIdentities,Get-CFDistributions,Get-CFGConfigRules,Get-CFGConfigurationRecorders,Get-CFGDeliveryChannels,

How can I clean this up and get access to AWSPowerShell in PowerShell?